# TypeScript: Exclude external types from the build output

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a firebase functions with TypeScript and I have the following folder structure in the project:

```
- functions
--- src
------ auth.ts
- types
--- authResponse.ts
```

Inside my `auth.ts` file, I import the type from 'authResponse.ts`.

And 
as the result, when I build the code inside `functions` directory, I get the following output in the `functions/lib` directory:

```
-- lib
---- src
------- auth.js
---- types
------- authResponse.js
```

But I need the full output inside the `lib` directory like this:

```
-- lib
---- auth.js
```

I understand that it's caused by the fact that I'm importing `types` from the outside.

Is there any way to prevent it from appearing inside the lib folder? I've tried excluding it from tsconfig, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your questions I assume you use [predeploy hook](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/index#hooks) for transpilation.

If so, rename `authResponse.ts` to `authResponse.d.ts`. The `d` stands for definition, so Typescript transpiler will know it is not meant to be transpiled.

Check out this guide for [writing definition files](https://definitelytyped.org/guides/best-practices.html).

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you!